# How to run an external program in parallel mode using python3

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a list of file names, I need to run an **external program**(**lastz** program) on them. The external program takes two input file and generates an output file and it takes 1-2 hours depending on the input file size.

My below programs run one external program at a time.

```
import subprocess


def run_lastz(input1, input2, output):
    cmd_string = "lastz '{}'[multiple] {} --ambiguous=iupac --ambiguous=n --format=sam  --output='{}' --chain --gapped ".format(file1, file2, output)
    print(cmd_string)
    process = subprocess.Popen(cmd_string, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    process.wait() 


file_name_list = ['1.txt', '2.txt', '3.text', '15.txt', '111.txt', '31.txt', '41.txt', '50.txt', '1011.txt']

for file1 in file_name_list:
    for file2 in file_name_list:
        if file1 != file2:
            out_file = '{}__{}.out'.format(file1, file2)
            run_lastz(file1, file2, out_file)
```

Now I am trying to improve the speed for running the external program which is possible by running multiple such programs in parallel mode.

I think multithreading or multiprocessing can solve the above issue and I am very new to multithreading or multiprocessing. Need some help on that. My goal is to run about 8 to 12 just external programs at a time and once that complete move to next set.

Comment: good tutorial on multithreading here https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm

Comment: Run multiple instances of your function in threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use multiprocessing, instead of multi-threading since it has GIL issue.

More info on [multiprocessing here](https://pymotw.com/3/multiprocessing/basics.html) !!!

For restricting number of processes, we need to use Pool class in multi-processing.

1. It creates set number of processes as pool.
2. Inputs are passed to set number of processes.

Check below code :

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def run_lastz(file_tuple):
    f1,f2,out = file_tuple
    print " Working with input -",f1,f2,out
    print "----------------------------------"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Start 10 worker processes
    pool = Pool(processes=10)

    #Then create a list of input list [(1.txt,2.txt,1_2.out),(2.txt,3.txt,2_3.out)....]
    file_name_list = ['1.txt', '2.txt', '3.text', '15.txt', '111.txt', '31.txt', '41.txt', '50.txt', '1011.txt']
    f_list =[]
    for file1 in file_name_list:
        for file2 in file_name_list:
            if file1 != file2:
                out_file = '{}__{}.out'.format(file1, file2)
                t_list =(file1,file2,out_file)
                f_list.append(t_list)
    #Map input list with target function
    pool.map(run_lastz, f_list)
```

**Note :**

For demo purpose, I have removed your original code from `run_lastz` function. Once you understand above code and able to run, modify functionality of `run_lastz` function.

*Also, it's my humble request to go through above link for more detailed understanding.*

Comment: can you please help me to restrict the number of processes? I would like to create 10 processes at a time.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I understood the concept and implemented successfully in my program.